# Swift ui copy and edit struct Identifiable Codable

Tags: swift, object, struct, codable

I have the following struct:

```
struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case title, message, background
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let background: NoteBackground

func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = Note(title: title, message: message, background: background)
        return copy
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to be able to copy and modify an object, with an id other than the copied object.

```
let note = Note(
            title: "Title",
            message: "Message",
            background: .url("https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/climaxmite.256.718018.jpg")
        )
let note2 = note
.copy()//clone
.edit(background: .gradient([
                            Color(red: 0, green: 0.95, blue: 1),
                            Color(red: 0.56, green: 0.18, blue: 0.89)
                ])) as! Note
```

How can I do any advice?

Comment: Why don't you use a `class` if you want reference-type behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want a copy and to change some variables of `Note`? Do you want this to change the original, by using a class?

Comment: Also, you don't need `NSCopying` conformance on a `struct` like you have, so you can remove the `func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any`. Just make your own `func copy() -> Note` to make the return type `Note`. You could also just not copy the object, and instead mutate the `id`.